# certificate issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-developer-program

My app can be built for simulator with no problem. It works great.

But it fails on being built for archiving.

I check the reason and it says that I don't have the right certificate for that.

My questions:

1. Do I have to pay to get "Developer certificate"?
2. Can I build for archiving without paying?
3. What should be written in the keychain access? I have something called "Apple Code Sigining Certification Authority", does it have anything to do with it?

I would love if some can explain the whole testing on my device issue along with where should I enroll or anything of that kind.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Only registered developers ($99 per year) can get developer certificates (which are needed to submit to the App Store).  Check developer.apple.com